# Realm can't decrypt database error in background thread

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I am using Realm Objective-C with Swift as I am supporting iOS7 in my app.

I use a function to write a block of code to realm in a background thread. I wanted to add encryption so I modified the function as so:

```
  class func updateRealmWithBlockInBackground(block: () -> Void) {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        do {
          let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
          config.encryptionKey = Utils.getKey()
          let realm = try RLMRealm(configuration: config)

          realm.beginWriteTransaction()
          block()
          realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        } catch {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            TXNotificationSystem.postGlobalNotification(text: "\(error)", textColor: UIColor.redColor())
          })
        }
    }
  }
```

I am getting error code 2: Unable to decrypt realm.

If I use the one that does the write on the main thread I don't seem to be getting this error.

Anyone know why it's giving me this error ?

Answer (score 0):

If your Realm wasn't encrypted before, you can't just add encryption by configuring the encryption key. Realm would assume that the file on disk is already encrypted and try to decrypt it.

You'll need to open up the Realm without encryption key and use [`- [RLMRealm writeCopyToPath:encryptionKey:error:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/writeCopyToPath:encryptionKey:error:) to write an encrypted copy. You can then delete the original unencrypted .realm file and open up the encrypted copy with the encryption key set.